# Insertion Sort function doesn't work. Why?

Tags: c

```
void insertionsort(int a[], int n){
    int next, i, j;
    for(i=1; i<n; i++){
        if(a[i]<a[i-1]){
            for(j=i-2; j>=0; j--){
                if(a[j]<a[i]){
                    next = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = next;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a function that should order the elements of the array in increasing order. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Now is the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is not quite what the algorithm states. You might consider not using
two nested for-loops:

```
void insertionsort(int a[], int n){
   int i, key, j; 
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++) 
   { 
       key = a[i]; 
       j = i-1; 

       /* 
          Move all elements in the array at index 0 to i-1, that are 
          greater than the key element, one position to the right 
          of their current position 
       */
       while (j >= 0 && a[j] > key) 
       { 
           a[j+1] = a[j]; 
           j = j-1; 
       } 
       a[j+1] = key; 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap `i-1` index value too and also the second for loop condition should be `>`.

```
void insertionsort(int a[], int n){
    int next, i, j;
    for(i=1; i<n; i++){
        if(a[i]<a[i-1]){
            for(j=i; j>0; j--){
                if(a[j - 1]>a[ j ]){
                    next = a[ j - 1];
                    a[j - 1] = a[j];
                    a[j] = next;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```